# How to upload application to Cloud Foundry using API (not CLI)?

Tags: json, node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to develop a simple NodeJS web app that can more or less replace the Cloud Foundry (CF) CLI. I'm following the [API documentation to send the application.zip to the CF Service](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/238/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html), however I get an error response `Unsupported Media Type`.

For the application part of the body I'm sending the application.zip file that is uploaded from the browser.

For the resources part of the body I'm sending an empty Json array. My understanding is that as there is nothing uploaded initially there are no pre-uploaded resources that I want to specify, hence the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Unsupported Media Type` response, I suspect you send invalid request headers to the API. There is a [CloudFoundry API client written in node.js](https://github.com/prosociallearnEU/cf-nodejs-client) and you may read the source code to see [how they upload the app code](https://github.com/prosociallearnEU/cf-nodejs-client/blob/fa0f2a6fd2243a2e56464007e92ee0f76002df90/lib/model/cloudcontroller/Apps.js#L245-L284).

If that does not help you, please refine your question and add some code that you have.